# Php Syntax Error

Tags: php, postgresql, syntax

I'm trying to update a table in php and I keep getting syntax errors.

Here's what I've got:

```
if (isset($_POST['inspect'])) {
    // get gis_id from pole table to update fm_poles
    $sql = "select gis_id from poles where pole_number = '".$_GET['polenumber']."'";
    $rs = pg_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
    $gisid = $row['gis_id'];
    pg_free_result($rs);

    // update fm_poles
    $sql = "update fm_poles set inspect ='".$_POST['inspect']."',co_date = '".$_POST['co_date']."',size = '".$_POST['size']."',date = ".$_POST['date'].",brand ='".$_POST['brand']."',backspan = ".$_POST['backspan']." WHERE gis_id = ".$gisid."";
    print $sql."<BR>\n";
    $rs = pg_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
    pg_free_result($rs);
}
```

This is the error it gives me:

> update fm_poles set inspect ='20120208',co_date = '20030710',size =
>   '30-5',date = 0,brand ='test',backspan = 300 WHERE gis_id =

The error message:

> Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at end of input at character 129

Comment: Your code is so prone to SQL injection it makes me weep. Dude, you are a security hazard to your site and company. --- You need to escape the freaking _POST before using in a query.

Comment: This is on an intranet.
Weep away.

Comment: Because nobody ever has a `'` in their data or a disgruntled employee with access to their intranet.

Comment: True, Quentin, but the majority of the code was already written before this was passed off to me. I use what I'm given. lol

Comment: @JeffCameron: Adding escape statements everywhere is rather trivial. Moving to PDO will take slightly more time, but will be worth it in the long run.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/php.html gives a crash course in how to do parametrized queries in PHP, which is a better solution that escaping the variables and putting them in your SQL statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$gisid doesn't seem to have a value, or it might have some strange characters in it, so your where clause is saying "WHERE gis_id =".

So how about escaping it with mysql_real_escape_string:

```
WHERE gis_id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($gisid);
```

And use var_dump($gisid) to make sure it's getting set correctly.

Comment: $sql = "select gis_id from poles where pole_number =   '".$_GET['polenumber']."'";
        $rs = pg_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
        $gisid = $row['gis_id'];

Comment: Shouldn't that populate $gisid?

Comment: Well it should, but I can't run your code so I don't know what's going on.  You could put a var_dump($row) to see what's actually being returned.

Comment: And try escaping as per my revised answer above

Comment: Hey man, not gonna lie, being a noob, I had no idea which way to go with this. After pondering what you said about $gisid not pulling any value, I realized that I had left out:

$row = pg_fetch_array($rs, null, PGSQL_ASSOC);

Which populated the $gisid field and made the whole thing work.

Comment: glad everything worked out!  good luck...

Answer (score 1):

A. Check your input (the data in the POST), maybe it has some illegal characters in it?

For Example:
$_POST['backspan'] = "Let's go to the parade.";

..would cause issues in SQL encapsulation.

[edit] nvm, I see you added the output from the sql query, no encapsulation issues...

B. See the code below, in the future it may help save typing time on concatenation. :-)

```
$sql = "update fm_poles set inspect = '{$_POST['inspect']}',
co_date = '{$_POST['co_date']}',size = '{$_POST['size']}',
date = '{$_POST['date']}',brand = '{$_POST['brand']}',
backspan = '{$_POST['backspan']}' WHERE gis_id = '{$gisid}';";
print $sql."<BR>\n";
```

C. Try putting in the code above or putting single-quotes aroound your WHERE gis_is = $gsid, like so: WHERE gis_id = '$gsid'.